# PieChart adding scrollview in achartEngine?

Tags: android, achartengine

How to adding **scrollview** in **PieChart Graph using achartengine** . I am trying below way to add scrollview

**1) Adding LinearLayout(GraphView) parent Scrollview

2)Other Way -mRender.setInScroll(true) but not working**

In  1st way not showing graph problem and 2nd way not scrolling the view

**How to graphview Scrolling (how to show piegraph with all legend item)??**

Answer (score 1):

Under the scrollview you have to insert

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: not working -xml
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/chartview_bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chartview_header" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_graphView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
          
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

Comment: try to give scroll view height as match parent

Comment: piechart graph move but legend not scoll down and up... I am adding mrender.setinscroll(true) this reason piechart graph scroll but in scrollview not scroll

Comment: what do u meant by legend

Comment: In graph i m showing piegraph with renderer.setlegenditem method